# Segmentation of the car license plate on the symbols

Tags: c++, opencv

To segment license plate characters I use for the brightness histogram. 
To solve the problem, I wrote this code:

```
std::vector<int> computeColumnHistogram(const cv::Mat& img) 
{
    size_t width = img.size().width;
    size_t height = img.size().height;
    auto prow = img.ptr(0);
    std::vector<int> histogram(width,0); //Create a zeroed histogram of the necessary size
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
    {
        prow = img.ptr(y); // Get a pointer to the y-th row of the image
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            histogram[x] += prow[x]; // Update histogram value for this image column
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        histogram[x] /= height;

    int max = *std::max_element(histogram.begin(), histogram.end());

    cv::Mat histo; 
    histo = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(width,max), CV_8U);

    for(int i=0; i< width; ++i)  
    {  
        for(int j=0; j< histogram.at(i); ++j)  
            histo.at<unsigned char>(max-j-1,i) = 255;  
    }  

    imshow("hh", histo);

    return histogram;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat img = imread(argv[1], 0);

    imshow("Sourse", img);

    std::vector<int> hist = computeColumnHistogram(img);

    for(auto &e : hist)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program represented on the image 1:

[Image 1 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d56Cy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d56Cy.png)

I tried many ways to determine the position of symbols, but all to no avail.

I found an article that describes a similar method using a local maxima. [Image 2 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp1MD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp1MD.png)

How do I repeat the result?

Comment: Can you give a link to the article instead of only the image?

Answer (score 0):

I would try first **thresholding** the image to get a binary image of symbols/background (for example: http://www.ijcset.net/docs/Volumes/volume2issue1/ijcset2012020103.pdf). After thresholding, it would be adequate to use a **median filter** to remove noisy-like pixels remaining after the segmentation.

Once the image has been median-filtered, just start looking for the first pixel in black in the image and perform **region growing**, to find the rightmost black pixel of the object (symbol). Once you have that, restart the algorithm (look for the leftmost pixel in black) starting from the rightmost pixel of the previous object. That way you will obtain the initial and end pixels of each symbol.